# No sound using pydub

Tags: python, pydub

I am trying to play audio with python. Here is my code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import _play_with_simpleaudio
from time import sleep

note1 = AudioSegment.from_file("C:/Users/Sinscere/Desktop/Piano/a#6.ogg")
play_obj = _play_with_simpleaudio(note1)
sleep(2)
play_obj.stop()
```

It runs without any errors, but there is no sound. I can play 'a#6.ogg' file with windows media player, so file is ok. I've got ffmpeg installed but it didn't helped.
I use VS code if it matters. However running python code through terminal returnes silence too.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried to reinstall all related python libraries: pydub, simpleaudio, even playsound. Also I tried to run a code without simpleaudio. Something like that:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

some_audio = AudioSegment.from_file('f2.ogg')
play(some_audio)
```

Changing AudioSegment.from_file to AudioSegment.from_ogg also had no result.